# Cluster deploy mode is currently not supported for python applications on standalone clusters

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to run sample Python program on my `Spark` cluster. The cluster consists of a master and two workers. Nevertheless, when I am trying to run my sample code, it swears:

```
$ spark-submit --master spark://sparkmaster:7077 --deploy-mode cluster test01.py
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cluster deploy mode is currently not supported for python applications on standalone clusters.
```

What does it mean? Is my cluster standalone? Even if it consists of 3 computers, it is still standalone? How to make it non-standalone to run python programs in clustered mode?

---

If I just do

```
spark-submit test01.py
```

it crushes with error

```
21/03/30 11:07:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/03/30 11:07:27 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
21/03/30 11:07:27 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:134)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:550)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:506)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:491)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:248)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

---

I wrote `test01.py` in the following way

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

logFile = "README.md"  # Should be some file on your system
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName("SimpleApp")\
    .config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1")\
    .getOrCreate()

logData = spark.read.text(logFile).cache()

numAs = logData.filter(logData.value.contains('a')).count()
numBs = logData.filter(logData.value.contains('b')).count()

print("Lines with a: %i, lines with b: %i" % (numAs, numBs))

spark.stop()
```

and it worked. Unfortunately, there are no traces of this work on spark master page.

Was it working distributed at all?

Comment: I have these same basic questions. The documentation around Spark is laughable and the answers you get on here just go round in circles.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Nothing's wrong with your configuration. As the error indicates, this is simply a limitation of Apache Spark.

Well for spark to run it needs resources. In standalone mode you start workers and spark master and persistence layer can be any - HDFS, FileSystem, cassandra etc. In YARN mode you are asking YARN-Hadoop cluster to manage the resource allocation and book keeping.

When you use master as local[2] you request Spark to use 2 core's and run the driver and workers in the same JVM. In local mode all spark job related tasks run in the same JVM.

So in Standalone you are defining "containers" for the worker and spark master to run in your machine (so you can have 2 workers and your tasks can be distributed in the JVM of those two workers?) (#  in local mode you are just running everything in the same JVM in your local machine).

Comment: So what to do to run Python jobs? Is Python supported?

Comment: You need to go throw a CI / CD tool like Jenkins , azure devops or cloud function if you are in the cloud refer to this link if you are interested, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html